# JQuery code to change visibility of a div tag when user reaches the end of the page

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, triggers

I am trying to trigger a popup at the bottom of a webpage when a user scrolls down to and reaches the end of the webpage.

The code I have works to trigger an alert message on the console, but within the same scroll trigger block of code, I'm unable to change the visibility attribute of the div tag I'm aiming for. I tried placing the script for the trigger in the header, at the beginning of the body and at the end of the body. In all three cases, the visibility of the div tag remained the same.

```
<div id="contact_popup">asdfasasdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdf</div>
    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                $("#contact_popup").attr("visibility", "visible");
                alert("Hello");
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you ever see the alert?

Comment: Yes, every time I demo it.

Comment: Ok, so the if conditional is working then.  So do you have some other logic/css that makes it not visible?  Because all your scroll logic is doing it making it visible

Comment: Yes I do have a CSS sheet in which I've specified visibility:hidden for the div tag. The goal is to change that attribute to visible when the user scrolls down to the end of the page. Is that not possible to do while having visibility:hidden as default?

Comment: Can you show us the rule that is making it hidden?

Comment: #contact_popup {
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: blue;
    height:30px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index:1;
}

Comment: Ooooooooh, hah, my bad.  dude, your using `attr()` not `css()`, :)

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton!